# Update version check in comment for Document Library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online, csom, version-history, version-comments

We are currently working on a migration from SharePoint 2010 to SP Online using CSOM .NET managed code.

We have migrated items for Document Library, unfortunately, we missed to insert version check in comment for a different version.

Now we want to update the same.
Is there any way to update the version check in comment for existing items.

Thanks in advance!!!